# pass char * to C DLL from C# string

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I need to use a library of C functions in a DLL from a C# application.  I am having trouble calling DLL functions with char * arguments:

The C DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CopyFunc(char *, char *);
int CopyFunc(char *dest, char *src)
{
    strcpy(dest, src);
    return(strlen(src));
}
```

the C# app needs to look something like this:

```
[DllImport("dork.dll")]
public static extern int CopyFunc(string dst, string src);

int GetFuncVal(string source, string dest)
{
    return(CopyFunc(dest,source));
}
```

I've seen examples using string or StringBuilder, or IntPtr as replacements for the char * required by the DLL function prototype, but I've not been able to get any of them to work.  The most common exception I get is that PInvoke is unbalancing the stack because the function call does not match the prototype.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: A `char *` is a pointer to a 1-byte character type.  A C# string is Unicode.  You need to straighten that out first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your P/Invoke declaration of your external function as such:

```
[DllImport("dork.dll")]
public static extern int CopyFunc([MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]string a, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string b);

int GetFuncVal(string src, string dest)
{
    return(CopyFunc(dest,src));
}
```

Comment: That did work; however the DLL function modifies one of the char * parameters; the string 'dest' in the caller remains unmodified. How do I get this change to return to the C# caller?  Most of the functions in the DLL modify passed buffers. What I will actually need to do is create a byte array with binary data, pass it to the DLL expecting a char *, and receive the modified byte array back from the DLL.

Comment: Try adding out keyword to the string dest `public static extern int CopyFunc([MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]string a, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] out string b);` or `public static extern int CopyFunc([MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]string a, [Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string b);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up tinkering with this and got it all to work by using byte arrays instead of strings. I also had to change the UnmanagedType to LPArray. Now I have the bidirectional arrays functioning as expected.