# How to convert string to char*

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a C++ method like below,

```
STDMETHODIMP ClassName::FuncName(CHAR* inFile, CHAR **OutFile)
{
    ......
}
```

This function is exposed like below,

```
interface ICPC : IDispatch
{
    .....
    [id(1), helpstring("")] HRESULT FuncName([in] CHAR* inFile, [out] CHAR** outFile);
}
```

However in my .NET project when I am trying to call this function, it is expecting `ref sbyte` for first parameter and `IntPtr` for second parameter.

```
void ICPC.FuncName(ref sbyte inFile, IntPtr OutFile)
```

The first parameter I have is a input `String` variable. How do I pass that as `inFile`, and how do I read the `OutFile` out parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass char \* to C DLL from C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987435/pass-char-to-c-dll-from-c-sharp-string)

Comment: c++ a char[] is a byte[].  Try following :             string input = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
            input += "\0";
            byte[] output = input.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();  As a IntPtr : IntPtr output2 = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(input);

Comment: Hi Ozul, thanks for your inputs. But that doesn't solve the problem. Because I am not using p/invoke to call the c++ method. I am directly calling the c++ method through interface. So I can't marshal it that way.

Comment: Hi Jdweng, I converted the string to a byte array and passed as a input. It still shows invalid arguments passed.

Comment: Have you tried adding `string` attribute to `inFile` in your MIDL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/string `[in, string] CHAR* inFile`.

Comment: It's defined in a C++ project. So I can't modify that to a string. However I can change it to BSTR. But the problem is, the function is called in many places (from other c++ projects), so changing the signature will break the existing behavior.

Comment: I think how the interface is defined in the `IDL` file is not correct. With the current types imported to your C# project. There's no way to pass a string as `ref sbyte` and there is no way to read a file from an `IntPtr` especially when the length is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of experiments, it looks like there is no easy way to convert string to a char* (string to ref sbyte and also the output file to be IntPtr). So modified the idl to BSTR and BSTR*. So I can directly pass the string to the function.